# Trying to add overlay color to an img in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an overlay color to an image I tried to use `background` with `rgba` color but I don't see the overlay color.

**HTML code:**

```
<img src="hero.jpg" alt="" class="img-hero">
```

**CSS code:**

```
.img-hero{
    animation-name: img-hero-animation;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    animation-delay: 1750ms;
    opacity: 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below two ways to add an overlay on an image with CSS:

1. Use a wrapper `div` for the `img` and its `:before` as overlay:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.img-container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: rgba(33, 22, 100, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659085402847-d58e44029505?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="img-hero"></div>
```

2. Use the image as the `background` of a `div` and a `linear-gradient`  as overlay:

```css
.img-container {
  height:100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(33, 22, 100, 0.4), rgba(33, 22, 100, .7)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659085402847-d58e44029505?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add background using rgbawith transparency  background: rgba(,62,84,0.82);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).